# Cannot update, repair, or uninstall Visual Studio 2017

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 Pro from the web-installer. I recently tried to update to the latest using the internal updater and I got this error.

```
---------------------------
vs_installershell.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because node.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

followed by

```
---------------------------
vs_installershell.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because ffmpeg.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

If I try repairing, reinstalling, and uninstalling from Control Panel and from the same downloaded web installer, same errors. I created an [offline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network) cache of installer files, same errors.

I don't recall specifically installing any ffpmeg apps. I do have nodejs installed, but uninstalling and/or reinstalling doesn't seem to help.

I found some [other posts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/the-code-execution-cannot-proceed-because/7a2ed59d-cf7b-40ed-858b-ad6a18ede890) talking about *different* missing DLLs (never node.dll or ffmpeg.dll) and followed similar instructions (sfc and DISM scans) and they don't seem to turn anything up or fix anything.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

and

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.15063.0

Image Version: 10.0.15063.0

[==========================100.0%==========================] The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: If `sfc /scannow` reported no problems then DISM would report no problems.  Why are you specifying an offline .wim file anyways?  Typically you would  simply do `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` otherwise you would mount the .wim file then point to that (which doesn't appear to be the case)

Comment: The article suggested running RestoreHealth and it complained about needing sources. I just ran ScanHealth and it reports 100% complete, no problems... so, _shrug_

Comment: Unless your installation is non-typical it should contain a .wim which is used by DISM.  If ScanHealth reports no problems then RestoreHealth wouldn't do anything anyways.  I could have told you that though that Visual Studio isn't a system file nor would fixing a system file allow you to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here’s what finally worked. I extracted the full installer from the web installer. This took hours. I recommend using a wired network.

```
PS> ./vs_Professional.exe --layout ./temp --lang en-US
```

And ran the setup program from that directory. It allowed me to uninstall (mostly) without error. It completed successfully, but the program Control Panel.

At least, this time, I could completely and successfully uninstall from Control Panel.